# Is simultaneous "user testing" possible in QTP?

Tags: performance-testing, qtp

Could you please let me know if can I test an application simulating multiple users in QTP ?

If yes, how can i do this?

Please illustrate with the right steps or point me to some useful documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use QTP as a GUI handling client with connection to LoadRunner.
Very detailed explanation could be found here: 
http://motevich.blogspot.com/2007/11/execute-qtp-script-from-loadrunner.html

Comment: Biggest limitation here is that you need one load generator with QTP installed for every GUI user instance that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

simultaneously user testing is possible in QTP ?

No, Only one QTP user can run at a time in one computer. If you try to open other QTP user also in the desktop it will show only one.

Answer (score 1):

More details please - what exactly would you like to do?

If you mean simultaneous user testing with QTP as a proxy for load testing, no, it is not a good tool for that.  You will want a real load testing tool (Rational Performance Tester, OpenSTA, JMeter, LoadRunner, et al).

If you are talking about scenarios where you need to have QTP running on 2 machines accessing the same record(s), or something along those lines, then yes, you can do this with QTP.  QTP has no special handling for this, but it is fairly straightforward to set up a mechanism to do this.

For example, if you want to create a record with user A and modify the record with user B, you could have a common file that contains the record id.  User A would write the record id to this file after creating it, and user B would read the record id from the file before modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

See Graphical Virtual User (GUI Vuser) Licensing for LoadRunner. Essentially you have QTP scripts that you can execute as a part of a performance scenario. This is a well known solution going back to the dawn of LoadRunner, where first it was a bunch of XRunner Sessions on Unix workstations, then came GUI Virtual Users on WinRunner and the latest incarnation of GUI Virtual Users is QTP only with LR 11 and above. Speak to your rep about short term or permanent licensing of GUI Virtual users with your LoadRunner environment.